# Node.js Express receiving postman as empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I'm working on a simple website and I'm having a problem when sending a JSON to the API.  The JSON will be received as EMPTY if is sent using the html/js, but when using postman everything works as expected.

The structure of files is simply the server running on node.js, an html page with his javascript to build the JSON and send it.

The html file code as it follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
</head>
Receiver Address
<input type="text" placeholder="Write the target address..." id="target_address"></input><br>
Message
<input type="text" placeholder="Write the message in plain text..." id="message"></input><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="accept"></input>
<br>
<div id="results"><div>
</body>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

The javascript file is :

```
var URL_API = "http://localhost:3000/nr";
$("#accept").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = URL_API;
    var object = new Object();
    object.L = 1;
    object.B = ($("#target_address").val());
    object.message =($("#message").val());
    object.po = "ProofofOrigin";
    var data = JSON.stringify(object);
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : 'POST',
        crossDomain : true,
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application',
        data : data,
        dataType:'json',

    }).done(function(data, status, jqxhr) {
            window.alert("Information sent successfully");
    console.log(data.B);
    }).fail(function(data) {
        window.alert("ERROR");

    });
});
```

Then the part of node which is executing when receiving the given POST :

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var updateStep = Number(req.body.L)+1;
  var ProofofOrigin = req.body.message + "Message signed - POO";
  var info_JSON = {
    address: req.body.B,
    step:  updateStep,
    message: req.body.message,
    po: req.body.po,
  };
  JSON.stringify(info_JSON);
  //res.send("Address :  " + req.body.B + " \nStep : " + req.body.L + " \nMessage : " + req.body.C + " \nPOO : " + req.body.Po);
  res.send(info_JSON);
  //console.log(info_JSON);
});
```

For some reason the req.body (where the JSON should be saved) is completely empty on the body, but if I send it using Postman it will work.
I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Have you added body-parser? https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser It's required for accessing POST body.

Comment: set contentType: 'application/json'

Comment: Thank @Ararat Harutyunyan thiis worked

Answer (score 0):

Please verify this:

In javascript (client side):

```
contentType : 'application/json',
```

In nodejs (server side):

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/doSomething', function(req, res) {
   var mydata = req.body.mydata;
   ...
   return res.json({result: result});
});
```

You need to include the body parser module to be able to parse JSON bodies.